# creating linear-gradient by getting background colors from two divs with onclick event javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project that will get background color from two different divs using two different onClick events.My Divs have hex background color values. I want to get them and concatenate them as a linear gradient, apply them to a parent div and also want to convert the same code to rgb.
Here is my HTML,CSS and Js

```
<div class="color ForeignCrismon" onClick="GetColorOne(event)"></div> <!--First Color Stop-->
<div class="color BrewedBrown" onClick="GetColorTwo(event)"></div> <!--Second Color Stop-->
```

Background Color of these two divs in Css

```
.ForeignCrismon {background-color:#C91F37;} /* Div 1 color */

.BrewedBrown {background-color:#E68364;}  /* Div 2 color */
```

Can anyone suggest me Javascript for this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried writing the Javascript?

Comment: @Harry Yes I have tried...
`code`window.onload = function (){
 
  function GetColorOne(e){
   var ColorOneCode = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

 
  function GetColorTwo(e){
   var ColorTwoCode = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
  }
  
 alert (document.write("Color One Code is" + ColorOneCode + "Color Two Code is" + ColorTwoCode));
  }`code`

Comment: Ok. but what should the background be when only the first click is done? Also, what should happen if it is clicked in the reverse order (that is, second `div` is clicked before the first)?

Comment: @Harry Color should be changed if both divs are clicked... I mean only linear gradient should be generated.. and if reversed, color should be generated as the sequence of click on both divs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Solution,
**Hopes, it will help you!**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="color ForeignCrismon" onClick="GetColorOne(event)"></div>
<!--First Color Stop-->
<div class="color BrewedBrown" onClick="GetColorTwo(event)"></div>
<!--Second Color Stop-->
<div id="ParentBox"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.color {
width: 100px; 
height: 100px;
margin: 30px;
}

.ForeignCrismon {background-color:#C91F37;} /* Div 1 color */

.BrewedBrown {background-color:#E68364;}  /* Div 2 color */

#ParentBox {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
margin: 30px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var FirstColor, SecondColor;

function GetColorOne(e) {

    var ColorBox = e.target;
    style = window.getComputedStyle(ColorBox),
    BgColor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');

    FirstColor = BgColor;

}

function GetColorTwo(e) {

    var ColorBox = e.target;
    style = window.getComputedStyle(ColorBox),
    BgColor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');

    SecondColor = BgColor;

}

function ApplyGradient() {

    if(FirstColor && SecondColor) {

        var parent = document.getElementById("ParentBox");

        parent.style.background = 'linear-gradient(' + FirstColor + ',' + SecondColor + ')';

    }

}

document.addEventListener("click", ApplyGradient);
```